# Enum does not hold its keys, only a ref to keys instead

Tags: kdb, k

According to documentation at https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enumerate/

> ### Enumerate
>
> Syntax: `x$y, $[x;y]`
>
> Where
>
> - `x` and `y` are lists

I suppose a correct way to create `enum` would be through giving lists to the `$`:

```
q)e:`a`b`c$`b`a`c`c`a`b
'length
  [0]  e:`a`b`c$`b`a`c`c`a`b
               ^
```

but obvious it is not. After reading more examples I tried:

```
q)mykeys:`a`b`c
q)show e:`mykeys$`b`a`c`c`a`b
`mykeys$`b`a`c`c`a`b
```

And it works. But then I've seen that my `enum` `e` contains its values and **only a reference** to its keys `mykeys`:

```
q)(key;value)@\:e
`mykeys
`b`a`c`c`a`b
q)`:e.raw set e
`:e.raw
```

So saving `e` to a file saves no keys! In a fresh session:

```
q)e: get `:e.raw
q)e
`mykeys!1 0 2 2 0 1
q)mykeys
'mykeys
  [0]  mykeys
       ^
q)mykeys:`a`b`c
q)e
`mykeys$`b`a`c`c`a`b
```

I know one could save keys with a neat *enum extend* functionality:

```
q)`:mykeys?`b`a`c`c`a`b;
q)get `:mykeys
`b`a`c
```

But why do enums act like this? - it seems like they hardly splitted apart into *keys* and *values*. May be in a big picture with tables, indexes, table splaying it makes more sense.

And how enumeration could exists just after loading from a file? Is it a semi-normal state when its keys domain does not exist yet?:

```
q)e: get `:e.raw
q)e
`mykeys!1 0 2 2 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design because, like you presumed, there is a bigger and more generalised picture.

Enums are primarily used for:

1. the sym file, in which the syms (keys) are always stored permanently in the database with the help of enum-extend `?`
2. foreign-keys, as per https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#852-example-of-simple-foreign-key

In the latter case, it would not make sense to also store the keys with the enumeration because the keys are contents of a table. It is presumed that if you will persist the enum then you will also persist the table which contains the keys.

A similar concept is column-linking - https://code.kx.com/q/kb/linking-columns/

Finally, the reason

```
`a`b`c$`b`a`c`c`a`b
```

didn't work is because the list you're enumerating against must be passed by name, not passed by value. So it has to be

```
`mykeys$`b`a`c`c`a`b
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing on a function argument which must be passed by name. I've found `get` who demands its argument to be a `symbol` too. It's like pointers in `C`, right? If I think of them in this way, a picture becomes more clearer.